# Wordpress: ID is returned instead of object

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields

I'm currently working on a wordpress site. I created a relationship field called `link_to_content` basically what I', trying to do is to connect a tout to a program. The relationship field is set to return a Post Object.
[image]

So when I go into the tout and select the program `schoolFood` as the value for `link_to_content` I should be getting the object with the porgram's data.
[image]
Instead what I get is an array with the program's id.

```
 {{ dump(tout.link_to_content) }}
```

[image]

I also see from the ACF JSON file the field being updated

```
+            "label": "Link Content",
+            "name": "link_to_content",
+            "type": "relationship",
+            "instructions": "",
+            "required": 0,
+            "conditional_logic": [
+                [
+                    {
+                        "field": "field_5f21c1d39f170",
+                        "operator": "==",
+                        "value": "Internal"
+                    }
+                ]
+            ],
+            "wrapper": {
+                "width": "",
+                "class": "",
+                "id": ""
+            },
+            "show_in_rest": 0,
+            "wpml_cf_preferences": 0,
+            "post_type": [
+                "post",
+                "page",
+                "programs",
+                "location"
+            ],
+            "taxonomy": "",
+            "filters": [
+                "search",
+                "post_type",
+                "taxonomy"
+            ],
+            "elements": "",
+            "min": "",
+            "max": "",
+            "return_format": "object"
+        },
```

Any idea on why this might be?

Comment: Hmmm, strange. Its hard to tell without bring able to see it. Have you ever returned just the ID (i.e. could it be a caching problem)? You don't have another `link_to_content` field somewhere else? If you dump the entire "get_fields" for the page, do you see anything unusual in there?

Comment: Is the code using `get_field` or `get_post_meta` to retrieve the field for twig?